# SpringBoot error : No bean named 'myController' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a basic program of "hello world" in SpringBoot

**Code**

MyController.java

```
package controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package di.prac;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import controllers.MyController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx=SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        MyController m = (MyController)ctx.getBean("myController");
        m.hello();
        System.out.println("*******"+Arrays.asList(ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()));

    }
}
```

I am using **eclipse** and created this project from http://start.spring.io/ without any dependencies.

I learned that Spring create the bean of *MyController* class with name *myController* ,but Spring is not able to find *myController* bean

**ERROR**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'myController' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
>     at di.prac.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16)

Please find and explain the error in the Project

Comment: Your controller is in a different package as your demo application class.

Comment: Place `MyController` in di.prac. This will allow spring boot to perform automatic component scanning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place your controller under sub package of `di.prac` like `di.prac.controllers` or use `@ComponentScan` on your controller. By default, Spring scans the current and sub packages where your main application is present. If you want to scan other packages too, then you can specify the packages in `@SpringBootApplication` as an argument like.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xyz.controllers", "com.abc.models""})
```

We should avoid putting the @Configuration class in the default package (i.e. by not specifying the package at all). In this case, Spring scans all the classes in all jars in a classpath. That causes errors and the application probably doesn't start.

Answer (score 4):

For your controller to be available in the context of Spring, you need to define that it is managed by the Spring container. Only the @Controller annotation is not enough, it indicates only the stereotype of your bean, as well as the annotations @Repository and @Service.

In cases where the beans have these annotations and are managed by Spring, it is because their packages that the spring is scanning to search for them has been specified programmatically or per xml. In your case, you should annotate your DemoApplication class with 2 other annotations:

1. @Configuration - Allows access to spring context
2. @ComponentScan - Packages to be scanned by Spring

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan (basePackages = {"controllers"})
   public class DemoApplication {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
           ApplicationContext ctx=SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
           MyController m = (MyController)ctx.getBean("myController");
           m.hello();
           System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames())); 
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered same problem, solution is simple.You just (me also) created package "controllers" on the wrong place. It should be created not in java folder but under folder with name of your project. Simple but deadly mistake. Your code is written perfectly fine.